# Ordenar datos del campo MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

En un campo de la base datos en mysql se guardan unos logs que realiza cada usuario en el sistema, lo cual los guarda asi:

- --> keys <-- --> fields <--
- id_visitas : 0
- run (new)  : 11111111-1
- fecha_inicio (new)  : 2017-11-21
- fecha_termino (new)  : 2017-11-21
- uurr (new)  : 65
- motivo (new)  : 11
- observaciones (new) : SORPRENDIDO TOMANDO LAPICES.

y la pregunta es como puedo ordenar o darle formato a ese dato, para que quede asi:

- Run:11111111-1
- fecha_inicio:2017-11-21
- fecha_termino:2017-11-21

Gracias

Comment: Hola! Fíjate que tu log tiene un separador entre conceptos, creo que es el ||. Úsalo para separar los componentes, y así los puedes reorganizar como quieres.

Comment: Te refieres al guardarlos, al seleccionar los datos de la BBDD, ... ???

Comment: y como puedo separarlos ||

Comment: ¿Cómo es el `SELECT` que te trae esos datos? ¿Usas `GROUP_CONCAT`?

Comment: Pues básicamente tendrías que hacer varias querys usando [replace](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace), para esto sería recomendable que crees un nuevo campo y allí almacenes el resultado.